# How to prove that $L^* = L^*L^*$

Tags: formal-languages

I need to prove or disprove that $L^* = L^*L^*$.

Intuitively, I know this is true, and I know I need to prove that $L^*$ is subset of $L^*L^*$ and that $L^*L^*$ is a subset of $L^*$.

But I am really struggling to prove that.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Write the definitions you work with, and how you tried to use them to prove the claim.

Comment: Hey, first, please forgive me for my English.

let x be in L*L*, 
that's mean that x is in 
({epsilon} union L union L^2 union...) * ({epsilon} union L union L^2 union...)
and that means that x is in (in this direction I stuck here)

other direction - 
let x be in L*, that means that x is in
{epsilon} union L union L^2 union.. 
and again I stuck here.

I know this is just the definition but you can see where I am stuck @Shaull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a partial answer, to put you on the right track. Try to complete it to a full answer.

Let's try to show that $L^*\subseteq L^* L^*$.

Let $x\in L^*$, so we know that we can write $x=y_1\cdots y_k$ where $y_i\in L$ for all $i$.
Now, let's assume for a moment that $k\ge 2$, then we can look at two words: $x_1=y_1$ and $x_2=y_2\cdots y_k$. We then have that $x=x_1x_2$ and $x_1\in L^*$ and $x_2\in L^*$, so $x\in L^*L^*$.

If $k<2$, then we can take $x_2=\epsilon$, and possible $x_1=\epsilon$, and the proof still works. So we have $L^*\subseteq L^* L^*$.

Can you now follow a similar scheme for the other containment?

Comment: yes absolutely, thank you very much sir

Answer (score 1):

What colleague Shauli says in his answer, or if you are bold and not afraid of infinite unions:

$L^*\cdot L^* = ( \bigcup_{i\ge 0} L^i )\cdot ( \bigcup_{j\ge 0} L^j ) =  \bigcup_{i,j\ge 0} (L^{i}{\cdot}L^{j}) =  \bigcup_{i,j\ge 0} L^{i+j}  = \bigcup_{k\ge 0} L^k = L^*$.

Do I see a hint of a Cantor traversal in the grid in this formula?